# Filter the data and display result ordered by no. of post

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

In Django I need to filter the data and display the result like. for example

```
Company3(20)
Company1(12)
Company2(3)
```

Here *"Company1,Company2,Company3"* are Company Names and inside the brackets *"20,12,3"* are no. of jobs posted by the particular company.

```
models.py

class User(models.Model):
     first_name= forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput())
     last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput())
     username = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput())
     email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput())
     password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
     companyname = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput())

class jobs(models.Model):
     emp = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     referencecode = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     jobsummary = models.TextField()
     jobdetails = models.TextField()
     key_skills = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I tried to give views.py is like

```
def search_result(request):

     details=User.objects.filter(jobs__isnull=False).select_related()
     return render_to_response('searchresult.html', {'details': details})

templates
<ul>
{% for d1 in details %}
<li>{{ d1.companyname }}({{ d1.count }})</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Give some ideas to display the results as like above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps a more efficient would look like

```
details = User.objects.filter(jobs__isnull=False).annotate(job_count=Count('jobs'))\
                   .order_by('job_count')
```

and then in the template

```
<ul>
{% for d1 in details %}
    <li>{{ d1.companyname }}({{ d1.job_count }})</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `d1.jobs_set.count` instead, to get the count of jobs.

So update your template to:

```
<ul>
{% for d1 in details %}
    <li>{{ d1.companyname }}({{ d1.jobs_set.count }})</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: output 
    Company1()
    Company1()
    Company2()
I posted 2 jobs for Company1 and 1 for Company2

Comment: ohh, it should be `{{ d1.jobs_set.count }}`, I mistakenly suggested `d1.emp_set`.

Answer (score 0):

You really should have a `Company` model; which would have made this a simple task with the help of the [aggregation api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/aggregation/); but for your case you'll need to do it in your view:

```
from collections import defaultdict

from django.shortcuts import render

def search_result(request):

    company_count = defaultdict(int)
    for obj in User.objects.filter(jobs__isnull=False).select_related():
        company_count[obj.companyname] += 1

    return render(request, 'searchresult.html', {'details': company_count})
```

Your template would become:

```
{% for company_name in details %}
    {{ company_name }}({{ details.company_name }})
{% endfor %}
```